# Difference between adding internal and external event listeners (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, addeventlistener

I have some `MovieClip` `class` that has `eventListener`, added from inside the constructor of the `class` (it's `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`). Now, I want to add the same listener externally, from **parent** `class`, for other purposes. Will these two interfere with each other or it's okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely legal to do this.

You need to have in mind how mouse events work. The event dispatching system inspects the display hierarchy of the object that triggers the mouse event. There is then a very root element - usually the stage - and the very bottom element, the event target.

Flash notifies now the entire hierachy about this event. If any of the elements in this hierarchy has a listener set to the mouse down event, it will get notified.

The notification is a 3 step procedure starting with the very root element going down (1) to the target element, notifying that element (2) and again bubbling up to the root element (3).

The top-down notification flow is called capture phase. To receive notification here you need to set the useCapture flag to true. The bottom-up notification flow is called bubblin phase. This is to what your parent is registered to by default if not set useCapture to true.

The target phase of an event follows the caputure phase. Here the actual event target that has triggered the event is notified.

Summary: Events are dispatched in a 3 phase procedure. Elements of a display hierarchy may listen to that event or not.

Found a web link here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's fine.  You can add as many event listeners as you like, they are all listening for the same event and will not interfere with each other.

Comment: simple and clear. thank you. by the way, how can i find out which instance of the object called the listener? i mean, if i have 50 instances of some class with listeners each, how can i know inside of the function which object caused the call?

Comment: Event object has 'target' property that stores object that caused the call

Comment: If you have a list/array of those 50 instances, you can loop through it and compare each one to the `event.target` property of the MouseEvent that's being sent to your listener function.

Comment: but isn't the type of event.target Object? what will be the result of comparison it with for example some Ball object? :SS

Comment: A non-strict comparison (==) should return true.

Comment: if (event.target == myBall) THEN myBall was clicked.

Comment: It doesn't compare the types, rather it copares the references. Thus if they're equal the objects are the same object. If you want to compare types then you can use the `is` operator.